# Why am I getting cannot find symbol: in.nextInt error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a little game in Java and it keeps popping up error:

> cannot find symbol

on `in.nextInt`. I've got other `in.nextInt`s in my code that work fine so I'm a little stumped.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player
{
     int difficult = 3;

     public Player()
     {
     }
     public void SetDifficult()
     {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("choose your difficulty:\n1. simple\n2. easy\n3. normal\n4. hard\n5. impossible");
         difficult = in.nextint();
         ...
}
```

What is the reason for getting this error ?

Comment: A quick glance at the javadoc would have given you the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have:

```
in.nextint()
```

you want:

```
in.nextInt()
```

with a capital I